# Bootstrap Carousel with Animate.css

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, animate.css

For some reason, I cant get a Bootstrap carousel to work with animate.css. The two work separately, but when compiled together its not working.

I am trying to get #line-top and #line-bottom to slide left/right using animate.css when the carousel transitions.

I can currently get the divs to animate on 'slide' but not 'slid'.

Here is a [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/71522)

Comment: what exactly is not working? can you provide us with a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) that demonstrates the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Place first jQuery JS Library then twitterbootstrap JS Library like

```
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>

<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Sorry, should have mentioned. all animate.css, bootstrap.css, bootstrap.js and jquery.js are included in the <head>

Comment: I am using the following '<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>'